# Are there plans to add Protected to typescript

Tags: typescript, protected

Are there any plans to add the Protected modifier to typescript?
Without Protected there isn't any way for inheritance to work correctly without exposing var/function to external classes.

Answer (score 2):

The specific request you could follow for `protected` support is [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/125).

As you can see, it's got a lot of votes. However, TypeScript is following the design of newer proposals/versions of ECMAScript rather than innovating on it's own in most instances. As `protected` is a ways out from being supported in ECMAScript/JavaScript, I wouldn't expect it any time soon.  Many developers have established a coding convention instead and used `public` for those cases where `protected` may have made more sense.

Comment: This is the right workitem to look at - it is currently described as a "TypeScript Future" currently (along with async / await) and is pretty likely to get implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request here: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1413

So if you vote, it might help :)
So I don't think it is currently on the roadmap, but only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.3 of TypeScript is available and includes the `protected` keyword.

[View the release notes for the protected keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/688)

```
class A {
    protected x: string = 'a';
}

class B extends A {
    method() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

var b = new B();

// Not allowed by compiler
console.log(b.x);

// Allowed
console.log(b.method());
```

Bear in mind that if you ignore the compiler warning shown for `b.x` in this example, the compiled code will indeed log the value from the protected member. This is because it is a compile-time construct not a runtime one (i.e. there is nothing to stop you accessing `private` or `protected` members at runtime).